# How do I register for an event on an object without the need for an anonymous class?

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm creating an android app.  I have a Dialog, and I want to handle the onCancel() event without using an anonymous class because it's cleaner and there are class variables I need access to from the main Activity class.  I'm looking for a way to register for events on an object similar to .NET, where I can handle it in a separate method in the class without the need for an anonymous class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) in the  Event Listeners section.

The first example uses an anonymous class for the listener; the second uses a method inside the Activity.  No extra class needed.

TL;DR Here is the code stolen from that page:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
        ...
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.corky);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // Implement the OnClickListener callback
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }
    ...
}
```

You can modify this to use `onCancel()`.

Comment: Thanks!  I just realized that I was forgetting to implement OnClickListener.  New to Java =)